# Query to count number of followers

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table, in which I will be storing the `email_id` of a user along with the user's followers' `email_id`s. Its columns are:

```
ID, USER_EMAIL, FOLLWING_EMAIL
```

Now while the user is logged in to his account, I want to calculate:

1. The number of people he is following
2. The number of followers he has

Calculating the number of people he's following is simple:

```
select count(*) from list where user_email = <logged-in email>
```

But how can I calculate how many people are following him in just one query?

Comment: it'd be nice if you add your code. at least your db schema

Comment: I HAVE GIVEN THE TABLE STRUCTURE.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal: Your Shift key appears to be stuck on. Can you please type in a normal case? This applies for the comments below as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN user_email = '<email>' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS following_cnt,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN following_email = '<email>' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS follower_cnt
FROM
    list
WHERE 
    '<email>' IN (user_email, following_email)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to change the field in your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM list WHERE following_email = '...'
```

To count both in one query, use subselects:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT count(*) FROM list WHERE user_email = '...') AS following,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM list WHERE following_email = '...') AS followers
```

---

> is there any optimize to store the data, to achieve this functionality?

Yes. Add an index on `USER_EMAIL` and another on `FOLLOWING_EMAIL`.

Comment: CAN I COUNT BOTH THE THINGS IN ONE QUERY?

Answer (score 0):

So is FOLLOWING_EMAIL the email address of a person this user is following? Or an index into another table? If the former, then:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from list where FOLLOWING_EMAIL="test@test.com"
```